# An incorrect proof that the Lie algebra matrix exponential is always injective. What's wrong?

Tags: exponential-function, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Suppose we have two square complex matrices $X,Y $ in the lie algebra $\mathcal{G}$ of matrix Lie group $\mathbb G$  such that $e^X = e^Y$. Then $e^{tX}$ and $e^{tY}$ define the same one-parameter subgroup of $\mathbb G$, and $$X = \lim_{t\to 0} \dfrac{e^{tX}-I}{t} \stackrel{?}{=} \lim_{t\to 0} \dfrac{e^{tY}-I}{t} = Y$$

Presumably it is the middle equality which is incorrect. But I think I've seen this method used to prove that the exponential map for the Heisenberg group is injective. Is there some property of the Heisenberg group that makes this equality hold?

Comment: If $\mathbb G$ is the unit circle then taking $X=\pi i$ and $Y=3\pi i$ gives $e^X=e^Y$, but $X\ne Y$. One-parameter subgroups are differently parameterized.

Comment: Specifically, your mistake is inferring that $e^X=e^Y$ implies that $e^{tX}$ and $e^{tY}$ define the same one-parameter subgroup. This fails to be the case exactly when the exponential is not injective!